# Hibernate inverse=''true" and problems when getting one-to-many

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-onetomany

I am trying to use the following mapping :

```
<class name="Category" table="CATEGORY" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" >
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>

    <set name="items" inverse="true" lazy="false" access="field" cascade="all">
        <key column="id" not-null="true"></key>
        <one-to-many  class="Item" />
    </set>

</class>
```

But when inverse is set to true, set of items is always empty. However, when I set inverse to false it works fine. 
Seems that I have missed something. Any explanations are highly appreciated.

**ADDED:**

Sorry for delay, I've made few changes to the code, but I am still facing a problem:
I am saving category with 3 items to the database, but when I retrieve that category back, it contains only one item. Here is the code:

```
public class Category {

    private long id;

    private int version;

    private String name;

    private Set<Item> items;

    public Category() {
        this.items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        this.items.add(item);
        item.setCategory(this);
    }

    public Set<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}



   <hibernate-mapping >
        <class name="Category" table="HIA_CATEGORY" lazy="false">
            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" >
                <column name="ID" />
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
            <version name="version" column="VERSION" ></version>

            <property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>

            <set name="items" inverse="true" lazy="false" access="field" cascade="all" outer-join="false">
                <key column="id" not-null="true"></key>
                <one-to-many  class="Item"  />
            </set>

        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

public class Item {

    protected long id;

    protected String name;

    protected Category category;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
        category.getItems().add(this);
    }

}


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Item" table="HIA_ITEM" lazy="false" 
        abstract="false" polymorphism="implicit">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" />


        <many-to-one name="category" update="true" cascade="save-update" access="field" lazy="false" outer-join="false"
            class="Category" column="CATEGORY">
        </many-to-one>
        <joined-subclass name="ExtItem" 
            table="EXT_ITEM" >
            <key column="id"></key>
            <property name="extProperty" column="EXT_PROPERTY"></property>
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** (by Stefan Steinegger according to comment by author)

Test case:

```
@Test public void lazyInitTest()
{ 
  Category cat = new Category(); 
  cat.setName("CTAEGORY_WITH_ITEMS"); 
  Item item = new Item(); 
  item.setName("ITEM1"); 
  Item item2 = new Item(); 
  item2.setName("ITEM2"); 
  Item item3 = new Item(); 
  item3.setName("Test"); 
  cat.addItem(item); 
  cat.addItem(item2); 
  cat.addItem(item3); 

  categoryDao.persistCategory(cat);

  Category category = categoryDao.getCategory(cat.getId()); 

  System.out.println(cat.getId() + "--" + category.getId());

  Assert.assertEquals(cat.getItems().size(), category.getItems().size()); 
}
```

Comment: something else is wrong. show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Only set inverse to true if there is a bidirectional relation. Inverse means that the set isn't stored because there is a redundant relation in memory.

**Edit** And of course it must be mapped into the same database field:

The set goes to `id`:

```
<set name="items" ...>
    <key column="id" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many  class="Item"  />
</set>
```

and the many-to-one goes to `CATEGORY`:

```
<many-to-one ... column="CATEGORY">
</many-to-one>
```

Change the set to `CATEGORY` as well to fix the problem:

```
<set ...>
    <key column="CATEGORY" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many  class="Item"  />
</set>
```

Comment: The asociation is biderectional.. I don't understand what do you mean by ISet?  it's java

Comment: It should be bidirectional in memory. You need to set the relations in memory correctly. If you can't find the problem, write a small test to reproduce it and post the code.

Comment: You are right, Set is already an interface. I removed it from my answer.

Comment: @Test
 public void lazyInitTest() {
  Category cat = new Category();
  cat.setName("CTAEGORY_WITH_ITEMS");

  Item item = new Item();
  item.setName("ITEM1");
  

  Item item2 = new Item();
  item2.setName("ITEM2");

  Item item3 = new Item();
  item3.setName("Test");
  
  cat.addItem(item);
  cat.addItem(item2);
  cat.addItem(item3);
  categoryDao.persistCategory(cat);

  Category category = categoryDao.getCategory(cat.getId());

  System.out.println(cat.getId() + "--" + category.getId());

   

  Assert.assertEquals(cat.getItems().size(), category.getItems().size());
 }

Comment: Comments are nor a good place for code however. 
What I am trying to show here is that the behavior of the test is the same - retreived category contains just one item so the las assertion fails. The code used to retreive category looks like this : 
public Category getCategoryById(long id) {
Session session = getSession();
  Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
  transaction.begin();
  Category result = (Category) session.get(Category.class, id);
  transaction.commit();
  session.close();
  return result;
}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have forgotten to map the  in Item but you're not showing the mapping so I can't confirm.

Also inverse means that Hibernate won't update the relationship information from this side. Make sure to also have item.setCategory(category) setup to properly trigger the database update.

Comment: Hello Emmanuel! I've posted the code above, actually Item was mapped.

Answer (score 0):

After you saved the Category with it's 3 Items to the database, did you check if all the Items were written correctly (as in connected with another tool and selected the Items, checking the category_id column)?

If yes: Did you check the Hibernate-Logs for the SQL-Statements generated?

If yes: Were these ok?

As a side note:

```
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
    category.getItems().add(this);
}
```

I keep seeing these all over the place. In fact I never did this but simply added the items to the collection and did Hibernate do the rest. Always worked for me and I can't remember seeing the other variant in one of my Hibernate books but can't check right now.

Comment: Yes. I have checked the records in the database, items are persisted correctly

Comment: ok, so persiting data works but the objects aren't loaded correctly. Can you change your logging configuration to show the sql statements hibernate's using to load the objects (preferably including the bind variables) and post the results?